# C++ remove doubles from an vector using <algorithm> and <functional>

Tags: c++

For a school assignment, I need to use `<algorithm>` and `<functional>` to remove all the double elements of a vector. This is what I came up with but it has an error.

What am I doing wrong?

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C3867   'std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>::size': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member  Opdracht5   c:\users\mike\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\opdracht5\opdracht5\main.cpp    38

```
bool IsEqual(string s, string s2)
{
    if (s == s2)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}


int main() {
     vector<string> coulours2 = { "red", "green", "blue", "orange", "purple", "orange", "black", "green" };
     vector<string> removedDoubles;
     removedDoubles.resize(coulours2.size());
     vector<string>::iterator it;
     it = unique_copy(removedDoubles.begin(), it, removedDoubles.begin(), IsEqual);
     removedDoubles.resize(distance(removedDoubles.begin(), it));
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for each (string var in removedDoubles)` is (also invalid) C#. You'd want `foreach` in that language (and to not use `var` since it's a keyword). In C++ you want `for(std::string var : removedDoubles)` or better `for(auto&& var : removedDoubles)` There are a number of additional problems with this code, including control reaching the end of a non-void function in `IsEqual`, probably storing `double` values in a `std::string`, passing a member function into a member function taking a size_t value using nonstandard syntax...

Comment: I editted the code

Comment: You'll probably have an easier time with things if you don't mix code with different purposes. Some of the code here is clearly from the last question you were working on when you posted here, and is supposed to solve a different (but similar) problem. You'd also heavily benefit from enabling warnings at a high level, say /W4. For your next question (since you seem to like posting here) you should probably work on making a [mcve], since that sort of thing would have isolated the problem for you here.

Comment: You're passing a default-constructed vector iterator into the `unique_copy` function. Use the proper way of referring to the end of the range covered by the vector: `removedDoubles.end()`. Note that `unique_copy` only gets rid of *consecutive* identical elements.

Comment: "consecutive identical elements" led me to the awnser thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the awnser.

```
 vector<string> coulours2 = { "red", "green", "blue", "orange", "purple", "orange", "black", "green" };
    sort(coulours2.begin(), coulours2.end());
    coulours2.erase(unique(coulours2.begin(), coulours2.end()), coulours2.end());
```